# GPS Android - get positioning only once

Tags: java, android, gps, locationmanager

Is there a way to access the GPS once instead of having a looper that constantly checks for location updates?

In my scenario all I'm interested in is finding the current co-ordinates and not a continuous connection with the GPS satellite. Does anyone have any ideas how this can be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First check if the last know location is recent.  If not, I believe you must to set up onLocationChanged listener, but once you get your first valid location you can always stop the stream of updates.

**Addition**

```
public class Example extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    LocationManager mLocationManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(location != null && location.getTime() > Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - 2 * 60 * 1000) {
            // Do something with the recent location fix
            //  otherwise wait for the update below
        }
        else {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            Log.v("Location Changed", location.getLatitude() + " and " + location.getLongitude());
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        }
    }

    // Required functions    
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {}
}
```

Comment: ye thats precisely my question, i set up an onLocationChanged and I would like to just get one valid location..how can I stop the stream of updates? Is there some command? Thanks

Comment: Short answer LocationManager.removeUpdates(). Long answer, see my update.

Comment: what does this `location.getTime() > Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - 2 * 60 * 1000` mean in above if condition?

Comment: @2619
As the time is measured in milliseconds, multiplying by 1000 gives you seconds, multiplying again by 60 gives you 1 minute, and multiplying by 2 again gives you the total time of 2 minutes. The if statement therefore checks if the location was received more than 2 minutes ago.

Comment: A good way but what I noticed during my own project is that if the last known location has not changed (even though it is stale in terms of time), then `onLocationChanged` event will not fire. Thus if you only depend on this call for whatever you do, it will not be reached since event is not fired.

Answer (score 42):

Dont use the getLastKnownLocation because that could be returning null or old data.

This code **Only fetches the location once a button is pressed** and not every time. People use to leave the location listener listen in every instance and that **kills the battery life** so Use the code snippet I have posted by doing lots of research:

```
// get the text view and buttons from the xml layout
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetLocation);
final TextView latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview4);
final TextView longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview5);
final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            mlocation = location;
            Log.d("Location Changes", location.toString());
            latitude.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
            longitude.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.d("Status Changed", String.valueOf(status));
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.d("Provider Enabled", provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.d("Provider Disabled", provider);
        }
    };

    // Now first make a criteria with your requirements
    // this is done to save the battery life of the device
    // there are various other other criteria you can search for..
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
    criteria.setVerticalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);

    // Now create a location manager
    final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

   // This is the Best And IMPORTANT part
    final Looper looper = null;

   // Now whenever the button is clicked fetch the location one time
   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, locationListener, looper);
       }
   });
```

Comment: yeh thats great

Comment: @msmukesh4 Just to be clear, This location listener will work only once, right? I mean.... If I click on the button once, it will give a single update and won't update after that even if the location changes, right?

Comment: That is a really great answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Dude, you save my life. I dont know how this answer is not the accepted. thanks a lot!

Comment: @msmukesh4 great answer, but this **freezes the UI** (too much work on main thread) and with async call not able to get location update.

Comment: @deepakkumar, in what conditions does it freeze UI? Slow GPS?

Comment: Thanks! Why `setCostAllowed(true)`? I think, we should add `locationListener?.let { locationManager?.removeUpdates(it) }` in `onDestroy`. Also it is very strange that inside `onLocationChanged` event we cannot update Fragment's view (change `TextView`s, colors, etc.).

Comment: The important part is `horizontalAccuracy = Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH; verticalAccuracy = Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH`. Without it sometimes `onLocationChanged` is not called. Instead of `looper` simply set `null`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/34626714/2914140. In API 30 this method is deprecated, but a new one (`getCurrentLocation`) is still not resolved.