# fragment does not refresh when back button is pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments

how can i refresh the view of a fragment, when the back button is pressed?

I've tried this in the onResume method of the fragment but it doesn't work.

Ok, here is the code

the layout look like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@color/mainscreen_bg">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/topbar"
    android:name="de.app.applib.TopbarFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/topbar_height"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_topbar" />

 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/position_list"
    android:name="de.app.applib.CriteriaListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/topbar"
    android:tag="CriteriaList"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_criterialist" />
```

The TopbarFragment has the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/topbar_bg" >

<ImageView android:id="@+id/topbar_home"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_ab_back_holo_light"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/none"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"/>
<ImageView  android:id="@+id/topbar_logo"
    android:src="@drawable/actionbar_logo"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/none"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/topbar_home"/>


<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/topbar_btn_push_abo"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/topbar_btn_info"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/topbar_btn_info"
    android:background="@drawable/topbar_btn_push_bg"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_topbar_btn_push"
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn=""
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

In the onCreateView() of the Fragment i set the textOn and textOff values of the toggleButton.

This Fragment is included in all activities.

Now, i want to update the text of the toggleButton when the user pressed the back button.
I set the new text in the onResume() Method of the Fragment. This Method is called but the old text appears in the activity and not the new updated text.

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onCreateView called");
    View v = inflater.inflate(ResourceUtils.getCustomizableLayoutID(getActivity(), "fragment_topbar"), container, false);
    subscrButton = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.topbar_btn_push_abo);
    setCountOfNewAdds();



    private void setCountOfNewAdds() {
    int countOfNewAds = ((App)getActivity().getApplication()).getCountOfNewAds();
    subscrButton.setTextOff(countOfNewAds>0?""+countOfNewAds:"");
    subscrButton.setTextOn(countOfNewAds>0?""+countOfNewAds:"");
    subscrButton.invalidate();
}

    @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setCountOfNewAdds();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Solution for the Problem was to use Framelayout in the layout to include the fragment e.g.

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/topbar"
android:name="de.app.applib.TopbarFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/topbar_height"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_topbar" />
```

and then use the FragmentManager to insert the Fragment in the onStart() Method

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    TopbarFragment topbarFragment = (TopbarFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.topbar);
    if(topbarFragment == null) {
        topbarFragment = new TopbarFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.topbar, topbarFragment).commit();
        getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }
}
```

then the update in the onResume() Method works

Answer (score 3):

If your fragment  call `replace()`, not `add()`  method to switch to another fragment (SecondFragment), your fragment will be called again the `onCreateView()` method when  the back button in SecondFragment is pressed

Comment: i dont call add or repalce to add the fragment i get the fragment in the activity with the getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById() Method

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the users back click in the activity that the Fragment is hosted in.

Then, you can call a refresh method in the Fragment to handle refreshing your view.

In your activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment yourFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById("ID");
    (TopbarFragment) yourFragment.setCountOfNewAdds();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was receiving user location using [`LocationManager`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38794291/2914140). First I opened another fragment (fragment B) and then returned to current (fragment A) with Back button. Then passed `view` variable (view == getView()) to a method that started `locationManager.requestSingleUpdate`.

After receiving `onLocationChanged` event that `view` variable *oddly changed to another value*, while `getView()` was right. So, when I later accessed any control with `view.textview.text = "aaa"` it didn't set new value, and the fragment didn't refresh. Also `getView()` is not always not `null`, it can be `null`, if you get it from `onCreateView`, but not from `onViewCreated`.