# locationManager.getLastKnownLocation() return null

Tags: android, geolocation, location, latitude-longitude

i dont understand why  `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);` return the location null. I gave all permission but its reutning `null`.

```
          if (isGPSEnabled) {
            if (location == null) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("GPS", "GPS Enabled");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: you checking it on device?

Comment: GPS will not work while you are in office or building.So you need also check using NETWORK_PROVIDER in such case

Comment: @Biraj I gave NETWORK_PROVIDER it still gives null untill after sometime. how can I ensure a not null value before proceeding

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had this exact same problem. It was because my device was not storing a last known location. I simply went on to Google Maps and pinpointed my location with GPS, then a value was returned for getLastKnownLocation()

Comment: You are correct, it is suggested to see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524381/gps-android-get-positioning-only-once

Comment: this fixed the issue for me, the app developer, but how can I do this without telling my end users to go to Google Maps for a GPS fix?

Answer (score 12):

You can request location updates like this

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(myProvider, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

then on the first callback in `locationListener.onLocationChanged` set your coordinates. Just don't forget to call `mLocationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener)`

Comment: So your answer is to just not use `getLastKnownLocation()` at all? why?

Answer (score 4):

Accoding to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29), it returns null, if the device is not aware of the last known location. Probably the GPS can not locate you. It takes about a minute or more, anyway. So try to go outside, under the clear sky, away from tall buildings, and wait until GPS can locate you.

Answer (score 3):

I used this method for get location   i think it will help you

```
private void startReceivingLocationUpdates() {

    if (mLocationManager == null) {

        mLocationManager = (android.location.LocationManager)
                mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    }

    if (mLocationManager != null) {

        try {

            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(

                    android.location.LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                    1000,
                    0F,
                    mLocationListeners[1]);

        } 
     catch (SecurityException ex) 
         {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);

        } 

       catch (IllegalArgumentException ex)
       {
            Log.d(TAG, "provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        try {

            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(

                    android.location.LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    1000,
                    0F,
                    mLocationListeners[0]);

            if (mListener != null) mListener.showGpsOnScreenIndicator(false);


        }
       catch (SecurityException ex) {

            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex); } 

        catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {

            Log.d(TAG, "provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());  }

        Log.d(TAG, "startReceivingLocationUpdates");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use GPS as provider then it gives your result with in 1 to 2 mnts so you have to contentiously check for that when get location stop and Network Provider gives you immediate locationwhen you request. So you dont get immediate Location lat lon in GPS provider.

GPS take 1 to 2 only first time then after it will give location you on call...