# Null Pointer when requesting getLastKnownLocation from Android's LocationManager

Tags: android, android-location

<del>I'm having the following error on android 21 and above.</del>

I'm having the following error, and there is no restriction on manufacturer or model for the error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackagesForUid(int)' on a null object reference
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1605)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
    at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.getLastLocation(ILocationManager.java:717)
    at android.location.LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.java:1200)
    at [...]
```

The call that triggers the error is either one bellow:

```
mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

I check beforehand if the mLocationManager is not null or if I have the necessary permissions. It work on most cases but I do have some crashing occurrences.

Does anyone knows what can be done to avoid it, or if there is any way to detect that it will happen so I don't request the location?

Thanks for your attention,

Comment: Just to understand, when you say some occurrences, is it on same device you see it crashing sometimes and working other times?

Comment: Seems to be something in lines of the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906926/locationmanager-getlastknownlocation-return-null

Comment: The crash monitor tool is detecting it on the store app. I haven't received it while developing. It not that often, but I have received over 100 occurrences.

Comment: Please check the link I posted. It seems getLastKnownLocation is not foolproof. A coldStart of GPS might return null for the device. As mentioned on another answer and also on the link provided for reliable location it is better to use LocationListener

Comment: He is getting null as the method's response. My code is crashing before the response is returned. I think they are different issues. Prasunnair, I think it is a different issue. My app is handling well when there isn't location available.

Comment: Gabriel, were you able to solve the issue? I have the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: @StackPWRequirmentsAreCrazy, I still do not have a solution for this problem. I am catching the exception and blocking location services until the end of that session.

Comment: Does this usually happen to you when the phone just starts/location is very recently turned on too?

Comment: I haven't got this issue on my own devices up to this point. This error I receive in production only. Can you actually reproduce it?