# How to stop automatic updates of Location

Tags: java, android, android-location

I'm creating an app which updates the location(lat,long) everytime a button is clicked.
I have set an OnClickListener on the button which calls this method -

```
 void getLocation() {
    try{
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //Default minTime = 5000, minDistance = 5
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, this);
    }
    catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But the problem is that the location keeps updating itself, in small time periods. I want the location to stay the same and only update itself when the button is pressed. What modifications must I make to do that?

Here is the onLocationChanged() method for reference -

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    locationText.setText("Current Location: "+ location.getLatitude() + " , " + location.getLongitude());
}
```

And also, sometimes it shows the location within a second, while other times it takes 10seconds. Any reason/solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there's no need for `requestLocationUpdates()` in the first place, when you don't want automatic location updates.

So instead of

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, this);
```

just use

```
locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, this, null);
```

Then you'll get only one callback per click on the button.

Regarding the time period when you get the callback: Android strives to reduce battery consumption as far as possible. That includes that the location is not detected each time a single app requests it, but requests are bundled, so that one received location is delivered to multiple apps or services that requested the location.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524381/gps-android-get-positioning-only-once)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to update when the button is clicked, you can simply store the value in the callback and not update the UI until you click the button

```
private Location mLocation;
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
     mLocation = location;
}
```

Move this into the button click method

```
locationText.setText("Current Location: "+ mLocation.getLatitude() + " , " + mLocation.getLongitude());
```

The accuracy of the GPS probably has something to do with how frequently its updated