# How to get location in thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my app, I need to get current location during app launch.
In my main activity, I want to ensure that firstly I find location, then I replace fragment. Because, I use these latitude and longitude information in my HomeFragment. For this purpose I want to use Runnable. However, when I use it I get this error:

```
Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    MyLocation myLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       myLocation = new MyLocation(getApplicationContext());

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myLocation.getLocation(getApplicationContext(), locationResult);
            }});

        t.start(); // spawn thread

        try {

            t.join();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                tx.replace(R.id.flContent, new HomeFragment());
                tx.commit();
    }
    public MyLocation.LocationResult locationResult = new MyLocation.LocationResult() {

        @Override
        public void gotLocation(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            double Longitude = location.getLongitude();
            double Latitude = location.getLatitude();

            try {
                System.out.println("lat"+Latitude);
                System.out.println("long"+Longitude);
                SharedPreferences locationpref = getApplication()
                        .getSharedPreferences("location", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = locationpref.edit();
                prefsEditor.putString("Longitude", Longitude + "");
                prefsEditor.putString("Latitude", Latitude + "");
                prefsEditor.commit();
                System.out.println("Lat:"+Latitude);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

MyLocation class:

```
public class MyLocation {

    Timer timer1;
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationResult locationResult;
    boolean gps_enabled = false;
    boolean network_enabled = false;
    Context context;

    public MyLocation(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result) {
        //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
        locationResult = result;
        if (lm == null)
            lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try {
            gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        try {
            network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        //Toast.makeText(context, gps_enabled+" "+network_enabled,     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
            return false;

        if (gps_enabled)
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return true;
            }
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        if (network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
        timer1 = new Timer();


        timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(context), 10000);
        //    Toast.makeText(context, " Yaha Tak AAya", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };

    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };

    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        Context context;

        public GetLastLocation(Context context){
            this.context = context;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //Context context = getClass().getgetApplicationContext();
            Location net_loc = null, gps_loc = null;
            if (gps_enabled)
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }gps_loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if(network_enabled)
                net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            //if there are both values use the latest one
            if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
                if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                    locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                else
                    locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                return;
            }

            if(gps_loc!=null){
                locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                return;
            }
            if(net_loc!=null){
                locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                return;
            }
            locationResult.gotLocation(null);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class LocationResult{
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }
}
```

How can I find location during app launch?

Comment: The  LocationListener interface should already be passed to a class that runs  in a separate thread... What is this MyLocation class?

Comment: @cricket_007 I added MyLocation class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979230/how-to-read-location-only-once-with-locationmanager-gps-and-network-provider-a

Comment: Why are you trying to use a Thread instead of your running your TimerTask directly?

Comment: And using a BroadcastReceiver and a Service would probably be the better approach here for running background tasks

Comment: How should I use TimerTask? @cricket_007

Comment: You already are... `timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(context), 10000);`... I'm asking why you think you need the MyLocation class with a Thread

Comment: I understand, actually, it isn't my solution. I use this solution. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227292/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-of-the-mobile-device-in-android/6621161#6621161) @cricket_007

Comment: Okay. In the top answer, though, it says "The call to getLastKnownLocation() doesn't block", which means it's running in a separate thread already

Comment: I understand. How should I approach the problem? Should I use broadcast with service? @cricket_007

Comment: Try the first answer there. If you think you need both  network or GPS based location, then you can continue to try using that MyLocation class