# How to get location just once in android (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-location, android-maps

I just want to get location for one time in android app. This is how I am trying to get location

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

In my Fragment

```
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient


// in onCreateView
fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireActivity())

// in function after checking permission
        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
                .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
                    if (location != null) {

                    }
                }
```

Now location is returning `null` everytime EXCEPT if I open google maps & run my app then it returns location correctly

Now I know that I need to call `requestLocationUpdates` before calling `lastLocation` but I am unable to find any solution in `kotlin` that explains how to use it for `just one time`. Every solution suggests getting location again and again.

Is there anyway that I can use `requestLocationUpdates` just to get location once?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7980707/9701793, this will help you

Comment: @rahat yes I already went through that, but suggested answers are either outdated or without any kotlin code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the latest version of `play-services-location` add the method `getCurrentLocation()`

```
fusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, null)
```

Comment: How were you able to pass null as the cancellation token...?

Comment: At that time the latest version was 18.0.0. @NonNull annotation was added in 19.0.0

Comment: I ended up just instantiating a new CTS, I didn't have one coming from anywhere else...